# Delete a member of a structure, and remake it as a copy of something else without using new

Tags: c++

So I'm working with an API which really isn't as functional as it could be. (Quickhaptics to be specific) In order to make something that I have work, I need to delete an object within a structure, create it again, (without using new, because the constructor for the object doesn't work the way I need it to) then set it to something.

I'm trying to do something along the lines of

```
delete data.cursor;
Cursor* data.cursor = (Cursor*)malloc(sizeof(Cursor));
data.cursor = data.cursors[index];
```

But this causes a crash(EDIT sorry, it doesn't compile is what I meant to say, but I don't understand the compiler errors)

Additional info: The way the API works, I need to send it a pointer to an item, which it takes initially and writes information to throughout execution. I'm trying to update the mesh on a cursor type object. It provides update functions to load in new meshes, but they are very expensive and can only run at ~3 fps. My solution is to load the objects into an array at startup, then just switch out the object that the program looks for as a cursor.

I'm generally new to C++, and my experience is all from sitting down and typing with no instruction, so there may be some basic C++ thing that I'm missing.

EDIT: Just to be clear, doing this works, just very slowly

```
delete data.cursor;
data.cursor = new Cursor("filename");
```

where data.cursors[index] was declared in teh same exact way at startup

Comment: A smart pointer is generally a better choice. Also, if you don't need to use a pointer in your code, don't use one. You can call the function like: `Cursor cur; someAPIFunc (&cur);`

Comment: That code doesn't cause a crash. That code wouldn't even compile. Please copy and paste real code if you want to talk about its run-time behavior.

Comment: My bad, was thinking it doesn't compile then wrote stuff about crashes. edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't compile because you're trying to declare a member:

```
delete data.cursor;
Cursor* data.cursor = (Cursor*)malloc(sizeof(Cursor));
```

is illegal, it should be:

```
delete data.cursor;
data.cursor = (Cursor*)malloc(sizeof(Cursor));
```

Also, since `cursor` is a pointer, doing

```
data.cursor = data.cursors[index];
```

will make the pointer point to that memory, so the previously allocated memory (via `malloc(sizeof(Cursor));` will be leaked. You're probably looking for a `memcpy` here.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I originally thought declaring it would be wrong, but I second guessed myself. And I thought C++ would have something like memcpy, but my google powers are weak.

Answer (score 3):

It looks as though you have allocated memory at an address using `malloc()` and then are setting the address value to some object, perhaps? What you most likely want instead is a line as follows

```
*data.cursor = data.cursors[index];
```

`*` will dereference the memory at the location so you can set its value. Note, however, this will call `operator=`.

Just a side-note:

Mixing `new`/`delete` with `malloc()`/`free()` is generally a bad idea since you need to keep track of *how* objects were allocated. That is, you must use the proper freeing calls with their respective allocation calls.